# Apex - Displaying a nested list after deserialising json

Tags: apex, json

I would like to make a http callout to import json and display the information in a visualforce page. The problem I'm having is that the json is nested and so I need to loop through the child nodes.

I have the following class derived using the json2apex application:

```
public class CHForm {

    public class FilingHistoryItem {
        public String DocumentDate;
        public String FormType;
        public String DocumentCategory;
        public String Document;
        public String DocumentDescription;
      }

    public FilingHistory FilingHistory;

    public class FilingHistory{
        public List<FilingHistoryItem> FilingHistoryItem;
      }
    public static CHForm parse(String json) {
        return (CHForm) System.JSON.deserialize(json, CHForm.class);
      }
}
```

In my controller class I can create a CHForm object (reponseForm) and deserialise the json into the reponseForm object using the following:

```
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
String chFormJson = res.getBody();
responseForm  = CHForm.parse(chFormJson);
```

but how do I then display a list of all FilingHistoryItem in the visualforce page? Do I need to create a list object in my controller or is there a way of directly referencing the list from the visualforce page?

Answer (score 3):

The direct reference, assuming `responseForm` is already a public property is:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!responseForm.FilingHistory.FilingHistoryItem}" var="item">
```

but it is probably cleaner to go via this:

```
public List<FilingHistoryItem> items {
    get {
        return responseForm.FilingHistory.FilingHistoryItem;
    }
}
```

referenced like this in the page:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!items}" var="item">
```

Answer (score 0):

To display a List in Visualforce page:

in your controller declare a property as below:

```
 public List<FilingHistoryItem> FilingHistoryItem{get;set;}
 or
  public List<FilingHistoryItem> FilingHistoryItem{ get
                                                      {
                                                       //your custom code to return a list of filling history items
                                                       }
                                                       set;}
```

Then in your visualforce you can display the list as below:

```
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!FilingHistoryItem}" var="fht">
  <apex:column value="{!fht.DocumentDate}"/>
  </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

you can add columns to display values of FilingHistoryItem attributes as you like.